# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present but Browser deny XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, apache, perl, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I have a really strange problem. I have a Webservice build with a simple Perl [`CGI`](http://p3rl.org/CGI) Script as a Wrapper to an API (to allow restricted Cross Origin Control). 
Anyway, to allow Cross-Origin Requests I set these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src *
X-Content-Security-Policy: connect-src *
X-WebKit-CSP: connect-src *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
```

where `my $origin = $ENV{HTTP_ORIGIN} // '*';`.

When the Script Requests the expected Ressource, the Response from the Wrapper is the followed (copied from Firefox):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 12:54:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language
content-security-policy: connect-src *, frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Content-Security-Policy: connect-src *
X-WebKit-CSP: connect-src *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Origin
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The Browser gives me the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/wrapper.pl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example2.com' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

I also tested the call with `curl` and `Postman`, but this worked as expected.
The problem is that all Browser seem to ignore the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, even when he is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. The Error was that I send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` only in the `OPTIONS` Request, not in the normal `POST`.